# CloudFront: How to clear cache

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to remove the cache from my CloudFront, but I am going crazy with this.

What I did so far:

1. Create bucket and set policy.
2. Copy the endpoint from that (I test it on browser, and it's working).
3. Create the CloudFront with the `Min TTL: 1 sec`.
4. Downloaded S3 Browser and set HTTP Header to `max-age=1`

But still, if I update my S3 bucket, my Cloudfront is showing files that I already changed.

Can you guys point me on how to do it the right way? If there is a way to just clean cache when I want, even better, I just want to upload my files, see if CloudFront is showing the correct thing on Web, then I don't care anymore about the cache.

Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

You can use invalidation which is described in the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html).

Recently this functionality was updated to allow to invalidate many objects at once. You can specify a path prefix and use : * to clear all cached objects.

[image]

However before deciding to use invalidations, please consider using versioned objects. There are many benefits to them described in the [article](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html) referenced above.